# Gradle: Check a file exist without file name

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I need to copy a file from one location to another location using gradle and stop further processing if the file is not in the destination. But I don't have the exact file name. I have to use the format of the file to check like ***.war or *.jar.** But assert is not working on  **path/*.war**  but if I give "path/name.war" then it is working. Any idea how to do assert for "path/*.war"

```
from fileTree( "target" ), {
        include "*.war"
        into '/usr/share/bin/web/'
    }
<code>
assert file("/usr/share/bin/web/\*.war").exists();  --> not working
assert file("/usr/share/bin/web/\name.war").exists();  --> working
```

Comment: gradle should error out when copy fails. Isn't that enough?  Other than that, your question is not very clear.  '*' is _not_ expanded or substituted in file("pattern")..

Comment: i  want the *.war file present in the destination otherwise need to throw an error. Problem is some times, target is not having the *.war file.

Comment: I tried to add this in dependency but it didn't work for some reason. So I put this as a check. I am thinking this is not the right way.

Answer (score 2):

Is it this what you are looking for?

```
File directory = new File("/usr/share/bin/web/");
boolean found = false;
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
for (File file : files) {
    if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".war")) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    // throw Exception
}
```

Comment: I added something like this,     FileTree tree = fileTree(dir: 'target', include: ['**/*.war', '**/*.jar'])
 if(tree.isEmpty()) {
  throw new RuntimeException("*.war/jar file is  missing ")
 }